# Clear all cookies for all users using PHP

Tags: php, cookies

I have a website written in PHP which allows users to create accounts and log in to them.  Each user is logged in until they press a "Logout" link.  I logged in on a public computer and forgot to log out.  I am now wondering if there is a way to logout all users currently logged in to my site using PHP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Haha, now you have a real lesson on why you don't make sessions too long. You could delete all session data though, if you would like to stop all existing sessions.

Comment: how would we know how your site is written?

Comment: change the cookie name in our php code

Answer (score 3):

Sure.  Just change the name of the cookie that persists the login.  Of course this will break the login for all users (which is, I guess, what you want).

If you are just worried about YOUR login, then I would think you could change your password if your cookie stores some sort of password hash.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into using PHP Sessions over cookies, I have been working on the same sort of systems recently. You can then store a token on a database, if you want to sign out all users you could simply expire the token.